# mysql upgrade (5.0.45 to 5.1.42) error

Tags: mysql

I am getting following error when we are upgrading 5.0.45 to 5.1.42. Do I need to use mysql_upgrade
or mysqlcheck ?

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. Created with MySQL 50045, now running 50142. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.

```
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3515)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1951)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2101)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2554)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1761)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2046)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1949)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:102)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:792)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:586)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in mysql 5.1 4 additional columns were added for procedures. Seems that somehow your upgrade skipped that step and now you are getting error while importing data.

[MySQL upgrade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-upgrade.html) should help you solve that problem.

Comment: If you still have same problem after do `mysql_upgrade`, just do it again with `--force` option. I fixed with that.

Answer (score 10):

If you're running on a XAMPP setup on ubuntu, navigate to:

```
/opt/lampp/bin
```

Then run

```
./mysql_upgrade
```

It should run a check through all your existing databases, at the end it may give you this error message:

> Could not create the upgrade info file
>   '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql_upgrade_info' in the MariaDB Servers
>   datadir, errno: 13

Not to worry, you can now import your db.sql script without errors.

In case you want to access your MariaDB shell, from the same location:

If you haven't set up a password:

```
./mysql -u root
```

If you've set up a password:

```
./mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: This actually answered my question.

Comment: For mac os with Xampp path for MySQL is /Applications/XAMPP/bin

Answer (score 0):

The exception indicates you should use mysql_upgrade.